# Error when installing Caffe on mac OS

Tags: caffe

```
Scanning dependencies of target caffeproto
[  0%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffeproto.dir/__/__/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc.o
In file included from /Users/cm/caffe/build/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:4:
In file included from /Users/cm/caffe/build/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_table_driven.h:34:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map.h:49:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/map_type_handler.h:35:
In file included from /usr/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:43:
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/message_lite.h:117:3: error: unknown type
       name 'constexpr'
  constexpr const T& get() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(union_); }
  ^
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/message_lite.h:117:13: error: expected member
       name or ';' after declaration specifiers
  constexpr const T& get() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(union_); }
  ~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

Comment: Welcome to stack over flow, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [This Github issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6359) seems to be about the same (or a very similar) problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Here is what to do:
- if you are using cmake try to add -std=c++11 to C flags:

```
if(UNIX OR APPLE)
```

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11")
endif()

- If you are using Make file, try to add the same flag to makefile

Hope this helps.

David